# Referencing twice related field for django model query

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I am using Django to construct a Query and I have 3 models as defined:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...


class Upload(models.Model):
    ...
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Region(models.Model):
    ...
    page = models.ForeignKey(Upload, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Given these 3 models I wanted a query that lists all the books and annotate them with a **segmented_pages** variable that contains the count of all the Upload that have **non-zero** number of regions.

Basically, counting the number of uploads per book that have atleast one region.

I am assuming the basic structure of the query would look like this and mainly the logic inside filter needs to be modified as there is no convenient count lookup.

```
Book.objects.annotate(segmented_pages=Count('upload', filter=Q(upload__region__count__gt=0))
```

Can someone please help me with the logic of the filter and a simple explanation of how to go about designing these types of queries using django models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite "non-zero number of regions" as "In the join produced by the query, the region for any upload must not be `null`", hence you can simply use [`isnull` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#isnull):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q


Book.objects.annotate(
    segmented_pages=Count(
        'upload',
        filter=Q(upload__region__isnull=False),
        distinct=True
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this is exactly what I was looking for.. 
just one more curiosity this will only work in case of non-zero or null regions, how would you go about modifying it to work for something generic for example number of region should be greater than 3?

Comment: @Krishna that query would be more complicated, will have to use subqueries, and perhaps might even need a custom expression.

Comment: Yeah I figured that! anyways that's fine maybe I will post another question following that trail at a later date..